# org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/tileslayout/mainlayout.jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, taglib

**New to Taglib**

I am developing a Web application using spring and tiles concept. when I try inserting a Taglib directory to my body layout part in tiles I am getting the following exception.

I tried inserting taglib under mainlayout.jsp alone but that didnt work. since each jsp works seperately we need to insert it in all the jsp. If I take out the Taglib from my bodypart.jsp the page is working fine.

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/tileslayout/mainlayout.jsp at line 23

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/tileslayout/mainlayout.jsp at line 23

20: 
21: <body>
22:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
23:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
24:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
25:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="scriptjs" />
26: </body>


Stacktrace:
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/tileslayout/mainlayout.jsp at line 23

20: 
21: <body>
22:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
23:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
24:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
25:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="scriptjs" />
26: </body>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:399)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.io.IOException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/tileslayout/mainlayout.jsp at line 23

20: 
21: <body>
22:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
23:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
24:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
25:     <tiles:insertAttribute name="scriptjs" />
26: </body>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.io.IOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/views/jsp/barcode.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:61)
    org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:125)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tileslayout.mainlayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f3(mainlayout_jsp.java:272)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tileslayout.mainlayout_jsp._jspService(mainlayout_jsp.java:140)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.resolveCssClass(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:462)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeOptionalAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:432)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:423)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:91)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.jsp.barcode_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005flabel_005f0(barcode_jsp.java:339)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.jsp.barcode_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(barcode_jsp.java:206)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.jsp.barcode_jsp._jspService(barcode_jsp.java:156)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:934)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:679)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:673)
    org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tileslayout.mainlayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f3(mainlayout_jsp.java:272)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tileslayout.mainlayout_jsp._jspService(mainlayout_jsp.java:140)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

tiles-def.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="bodypage" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Barcode Generation"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/badypart.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition> 

</tiles-definitions>
```

tiles-template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/views/tileslayout/mainlayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value=""></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="stylecss" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/firststylecss.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/firstheader.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="body" value=""></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/firstfooter.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="scriptjs" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/firstscriptjs.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>



</tiles-definitions>
```

mainlayout.xml

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<c:set var="webapp_path" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"
    scope="session" />
<link type="image/x-icon"
    href="<c:out value='${webapp_path}'/>/images/favicon.ico" rel="icon">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="stylecss" />
</head>

<body>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="scriptjs" />
</body>

</html>
```

bodypart.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="s"%>

    <div class="container">
        Hello World
        Here would like to use to spring form and jslt tags
    </div>
```